# How effectively updatie complex large object in REST?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, optimization

Suppose I have a complex object from html page which is mapped to this JSON structure:

```
{
    id:"", //is not shown to user
    title : "",
    description: "",
    summary: "",
    // other too many fields
}
```

To update this record with "common" REST approach I should use:

```
- POST rest/record/{id}
```

With "common" approach *entirely record* object is marshalled to JSON object and is passed to REST service, then this  *entirely object* is validated, passed to SQL query to data base and DB engine updates a record with *all* data. But what if user just update **one** symbol in the title?

In that case I should split this object into several:

```
{
    id:"", //is not shown to user
    { recordId:"", title : "",         } ,
    { recordId:"", description: "",    } ,
    { recordId:"", summary: "",        } ,
    // other too many fields
}
```

How I should reorganize rest URLs? Like that:

```
- POST rest/record/{id}/title
- POST rest/record/{id}/description
- POST rest/record/{id}/summary
- others
```

Is this approach with URL good or bad (I mean both for javaScript from end and REST back end programming)? Is there any other approaches to handle this problem?

Comment: Why would you need multiple URLs? Just a single URL with multiple parameters would suffice I guess.!

Comment: A url-per-attribute is crazy. If I update 2 attributes, is that 2 calls? What about 3 or 4 attributes? Are you going to permute all the possible attribute urls? REST should be about presenting resources. Is your HTML page really presenting multiple resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using POST, use PATCH and send only what's been changed:

```
PATCH rest/record/{id}

Data: { title: "new title" }
```

URLs such as rest/record/{id}/title, rest/record/{id}/summary, etc. aren't really RESTfull since they are not resources but properties of a resource.

Answer (score 0):

See this past question for some exploration of options here (include PATCH).

[Best practice for partial updates in a RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443324/best-practice-for-partial-updates-in-a-restful-service)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

- use `PATCH` and send only the `title`
- use `PUT` and send the whole data again
- use `PUT` and use the property as a sub-resource with url: `/resource/title`

(`POST` is not idempotent, so you should not use that for update)